# Taxes on Roth IRA earnings withdrawals <59.5 but >5 years

Tags: united-states, taxes, roth-ira, withdrawal, penalty

Homebuyers, education, disability, etc. exceptions aside, if you are **less than 59.5 years old** but make a withdrawal of earnings from a Roth IRA account that's been **open for more than 5 years**, do you also pay the 10% penalty on top of the taxes?

In other words, does the amount of time that the account has been open matter at all if withdrawals are made before age 59.5?

[image: treatment of earnings in roth ira]

Comment: You don't withdraw earnings from a Roth IRA until you have first withdrawn all contributions and conversions from other tax-deferred plans.  Indeed, _you_ cannot specify that you want the withdrawal to count as: the IRS specifies that contributions come out first (always nontaxable and without penalty), then conversions in the order they went in (penalties might apply), and _then_ earnings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Yes**, there are taxes and penalty on that withdrawal of earnings.

For a withdrawal to be a "qualified distribution", *both* of the conditions must be true: 1) Roth IRA must be open for at least 5 years, and 2) the person must be age 59.5 or meet one of the other exceptions. Failing to meet both conditions, it is a "non-qualified distribution". And a non-qualified distribution of the earnings part of the money (which would only happen if all the contribution has already been withdrawn) is subject to both tax and penalty. See Figure 2-1 in Publication 590-B for a flow-chart that describes whether a withdrawal from Roth IRA is a qualified distribution or not.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this section of the IRS tax code 590: https://www.irs.gov/publications/p590b#en_US_2016_publink1000231061

There is an "and" between the 59½ part and the > 5 years part. Both requirements must be met for the distribution to be qualified. There are other exceptions and the chart below may be helpful.

[image: Roth IRA qualified distribution flowchart]

Comment: That flowchart doesn't answer the question, because the final box reads "it *may* be subject to the 10% additional tax" which doesn't tell you whether the penalty applies or not.